# Linear equations problem from CAT

Tags: arithmetic, recreational-mathematics

How do I solve this question. Here is what I've been thinking: lotion A can relieve 75 spasms and lotion B 120 spasms. So going by options buying only lotion B would be cheaper right? Is my reasoning correct? Or is there a more sound reasoning to this problem?

One bottle of Lotion A can be applied three times and costs Rs. 25. Similarly one bottle of Lotion B can be applied 4 times and costs Rs. 30. For each application, Lotion A relieves 25 spasms while Lotion B relieves 30 spasms. Rahul was injured in a football game and has 200 spasms on his body. Which combination of Lotions should he buy if he wants to minimize the cost?
A) Half Lotion A & Half B
B) Lotion A
C) Lotion B

## LinearEquation

Comment: Yes, your reasoning is correct.

Comment: @Don Thousand you mean option C) lotion B should be the right answer, right?

Comment: Did you swap the choices?

Comment: Nope I had typed option B in the description above the question when I actually meant to write lotion B